# Передача данных без сервера

Tags: c#, передача-данных

К программе нужно добавить функционал передачи данных между ноутбуками. Написана на С#.
Есть доступ к интернету через WiFi. Есть пара ноутбуков.

- Как передать файл с одного на другой?
- Как найти ір адрес другого ноутбука?

Как вариант можно использовать торрент сеть, но тогда другой вопрос.
Как ее прикрутить к С# проекту?

Comment: Чем torrent сеть не подходит?

Comment: @cpp_user, и все же torrent это не совсем без сервера (он ведь нужен, чтобы ноуты увидели друг-друга).

Comment: @avp, Что значит увидели друг друга? Почему они не могут увидеть друг друга без сервера?

Comment: Чем по локальной сети не вариант?

Comment: @cpp_user, потому что, они узнают IP (с кем соединяться для перекачки) от сервера. Сначала, тот что раздает файлы соединяется с сервером (у сервера есть внешний IP и он где-то прописан) и сервер запоминает его IP. Потом тот кто хочет читать запрашивает сервер о файле и получает в ответе IP откуда надо читать. Хотя, этот IP может быть и динамическим (проброшенным из NAT-а). Этим пробросом на ближайшем роутере должен управлять по протоколу UPnP раздающий компьютер.

Comment: Leroy, возможно ваше решение лежит в IPv6, но мне эту область надо еще изучать и изучать... В любом случае понятно, что хотя бы один должен иметь внешний IP.

Comment: @avp, по идее запрашивающая сторона может сначала получить торрент файл например по почте, а в самом торрент файле будет указано откуда и что качать в таком случае сервер не нужен.

Comment: @cpp_user, в этом случае будет нужен *почтовый сервер* (опять же с общедоступным и известным IP (и прописанный в DNS)).

Comment: @avp это для примера, торрент файл может быть откуда угодно - да хоть на флешке кто то может принести. Но факт в том что сервер не нужен.

Comment: @cpp_user, если для примера, то обмениваться файлами между ноутами тоже можно посредством флэшек и голубей. Кстати, в вашем примере принесенный на флешке торрент-файл будет актуален только если IP раздающего ноута не изменился, т.е. если он статический (а в этом случае сам такой ноут надо рассматривть как сервер).

Comment: @avp есстественно что один из клиентов может быть и сервером одновременно, но торрент как бэ технология где все клиенты могут быть и сервером чтобы если один из серверов упал то раздача не пострадала бы.

Answer (score 5):

Вы пытаетесь решить две раздельных проблемы (в каждой из которых "сервер" используется в своем смысле)

Первая - поиск второго ноутбука. В этой проблеме "сервер" - это какая-то машина, которая знает про все ноутбуки, и к которой ноуты обращаются за списком других ноутов. От этого сервера можно избавится. В [`System.Net.PeerToPeer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.peertopeer?view=net-5.0) есть пачка классов для поддержки одноранговых сетей. Примеры слишком объемны чтобы привести их в ответе, но можете начать с [MSDN Blogs: Writing Peer-to-Peer Applications Using .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/p2p/writing-peer-to-peer-applications-using-net-part-1-pnrp):

Регистрация peer:

```
PeerName peerName = new PeerName("MikesWebServer", PeerNameType.Secured);

PeerNameRegistration pnReg = new PeerNameRegistration();
pnReg.PeerName = peerName;
pnReg.Port = 80;

//OPTIONAL
//The properties set below are optional.  You can register a PeerName without setting these properties
pnReg.Comment = "up to 39 unicode char comment";
pnReg.Data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("A data blob associated with the name");

/*
 * OPTIONAL
 *The properties below are also optional, but will not be set (ie. are commented out) for this example
 *pnReg.IPEndPointCollection = // a list of all {IPv4/v6 address, port} pairs to associate with the peername
 *pnReg.Cloud = //the scope in which the name should be registered (local subnet, internet, etc)
*/

//Starting the registration means the name is published for others to resolve
pnReg.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Registration of Peer Name: {0} complete.", peerName.ToString());
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the registration and close the program");
Console.ReadKey();

pnReg.Stop();
```

Поиск и получение информации о зарегистрованных:

```
// create a resolver object to resolve a peername
PeerNameResolver resolver = new PeerNameResolver();
// the peername to resolve must be passed as the first command line argument to the application
PeerName peerName = new PeerName(args[0]);
// resolve the PeerName - this is a network operation and will block until the resolve completes
PeerNameRecordCollection results = resolver.Resolve(peerName);
 
// Display the data returned by the resolve operation
Console.WriteLine("Results for PeerName: {0}", peerName);
Console.WriteLine();
int count = 1;
foreach (PeerNameRecord record in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Record #{0} results...", count);
   
    Console.Write("Comment:");
    if (record.Comment != null)
    {
        Console.Write(record.Comment);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
 
    Console.Write("Data:");
    if (record.Data != null)
    {
        Console.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(record.Data));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
 
    Console.WriteLine("Endpoints:");
    foreach (IPEndPoint endpoint in record.EndPointCollection){
        Console.WriteLine("\t Endpoint:{0}", endpoint);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
 
    count++;
}
 
Console.ReadKey();
```

Вторая - собственно передача файла. Тут "сервер" - это комп, принимающий входящее соединение. Или комп, отдающий файл. Т.к. к этому моменту у вас будет адрес второго ноута, то достаточно взять [любой пример по работе с сокетами](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/network-programming/synchronous-client-socket-example), вычитать файл как массив байт, и передать его на другую сторону вместо строки из примера.  И если вдруг не заработает - оформить это отдельным вопросом.